# Writing a script to check if the output of a command is "3"

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I'm trying to write a script to run a command and if the output of the command is 3 then script should exit and if it's not 3 then the script should send an email to let me know the count is not 3. 
I wrote this code below but for some reason every time I run it, i keep getting email saying the output is not 3 even though it's 3.

```
#!/bin/bash

Server_Count=""
   nslookup servers | grep -i "Address: 10" | wc -l > /dev/null
   if [ $? == 3 ]; then
       Server_Count="$?"
else
   echo "Server Count is not 3 .. Please check" | mail -s "Server count issue" Katkota@katkota.com

fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$?` will be the exit code of the previous command not the result of the previous command.  So assuming the command is successful, `$?` will be 0.

You want command substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash

server_count=$(nslookup servers | grep -i "Address: 10" | wc -l)
if [[ "$server_count" -ne 3 ]]; then
  echo "Server Count is not 3 .. Please check" | mail -s "Server count issue" Katkota@katkota.com
fi
```

This will set `server_count` to the results of `wc -l` so there is no need to set it again in your if statement.  Therefore I have negated the if check (if server count **does not** equal 3 send the email, otherwise do nothing).

Also the `-ne` check is being used here which is the correct check for integer comparison.

On a side note you were using the POSIX shell test `[ ... ]` with a bash comparison operator `==`.  This will still work on many systems but beware when using `[ ... ]` you should use `=` and when using `[[ ... ]]` you can use either `=` or `==`.

Comment: grep can count: `server_count=$( nslookup servers | grep -c "Address: 10" )`

Comment: And another `grep`  after that: `| grep -qxF 3` ... and you don't need the variable.

Answer (score 0):

[As Jesse_b explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/461907/116858), your code does not work since you are looking at the return status of `wc -l` rather than the data returned from it.

```
if nslookup servers | grep -c -iF "Address: 10" | ! grep -q -xF 3; then
    echo 'Server count is not 3... please check' | mail -s 'Server count issue' Katkota@katkota.com
fi
```

This gets rid of having to save things into variables by counting the number of lines that matches the given string in the output of `nslookup`, and if that count is not exactly three, it will send an email.

With `-c`, `grep` will output the number of lines that matches the given pattern. The `-q` option to `grep` stops grep from generating output.  Here, we're only interested in whether `grep` matches the `3` or not, and we check this by its return status. With `-x` we force a match across a whole line (i.e. we will match only `3` and not `30`). The `-F` option makes `grep` do a string match instead of a regular expression match.